# Implementing Slider With hundreds of Images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I want to create a gallery which will fetch data from a json source . I am listing images in with infinite scrolling . Now when a user clicks one of image I need to show that image on another page and than they can click next/previous to see images as they are shown on 1st page .

Problem is that how can I figure out next/previous image on another page when user clicks it . User might reach to point where he has seen all images as it was on 1st page so it needs to go to next set of images .

I will appreciate any help .

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of where you are in your array of images by using $_SESSION variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the images an ID (perhaps their index inside the JSON object) and then pass that in the URL as a GET request.

For example, the first image could be called as: http://www.example.com/showImage.php?id=1

You can fetch the image data from that index on the showImage page by referencing the JSON object (this will represent one of the instances in the JSON object).

```
$image_object = json_decode($your_json_object)[$_GET['id']];
```

Simply iterate the index to get next and previous:

```
$next = ($_GET['id'] == sizeof(json_decode($your_json_object)))? ++$_GET['id'] : 1;
$previous = ($_GET['id'] == 1)? sizeof(json_decode($your_json_object)) : --$_GET['id'];
```

Then use the html to create the links

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/showImage.php?id=<?= $next ?>">Next</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/showImage.php?id=<?= $previous ?>">Previous</a>
```

I have not tested this and went on what I understood from the original post.